# SQL: Group by - further attribute with largest quantity

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm new to SQL and facing following problem:

This is my table:

```
name   city  people
-----|-----|--------|
John | A   | 5      | 
Ben  | D   | 6      | 
John | A   | 5      | 
Ben  | A   | 5      | 
John | B   | 8      | 
Ben  | D   | 6      |
```

I want to group by the name and receive associated to the name that city with the largest quantity. As a second query, instead of the largest quantity, that city with the highest sum of inhabitants.

This would be the outcome for the first query:

```
name   city 
-----|-----|
John | A   |
Ben  | D   |
```

Thank you!

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: School work? What have you tried? Show us your current queries and we can assist you to the correct solutions.

Comment: Why city `A` with 5 people for John where city `B` has 8 people? Why there are duplicate entries for user/cities?

Comment: Before ask some thing , try your self, If you have google , you can find the solution easily

Comment: Every name can be related to different cities, also the same city. The example is not very good, i assume. But my actual problem is not easier...

I tried to get the maximum count like this:
    select max(counted) from (select city, count(city) as counted from table group by city)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "to the name that city with the largest quantity". What I understood was you sum the column 'people' per couple (name, city), thus (John, A) would be 10 and (John, B) would be 8, and you take the max value to get (John, A).

In this case, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    city 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        name, 
        city, 
        SUM(people) AS tot 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY name, city 
    ORDER BY name ASC, tot DESC) AS a 
GROUP BY name ;
```

As for the city with the largest number of inhabitants, you just have to group by city and sum the column people and take the max:

```
SELECT 
    city, 
    SUM(people) AS nb_inhabitants 
FROM table 
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY nb_inhabitants DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, your first code is what i have searched for! :)

What would i do, if i ignore the people and just count the cities per name?
Meaning (john,a)=2, (john,b)=1, so i get (John, A)
Replace sum(people) with count(city) ?

Comment: Yes, you remove SUM(people) in the inner select, replace city by COUNT(city), group only by name and order by count(city) desc. The outer select should be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, city, sum( people )
FROM `detail`
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY people ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I am not really understand what your are expecting ,but I guess you want to do this thing.

Description :  I am group by people from there name , and got sum of the  people and make them ASC order.  I am not sure your are expect this thing.

You can also , group people by their city

```
SELECT name, city, sum( people )
FROM `detail`
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY people ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

If this not you expect , Please , further describe question ,we will try to give some answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have tried by making a table as per your sample data,

```
CREATE TABLE KaiTable
(
    NAME       VARCHAR(50)
   ,city       CHAR(1)
   ,people     INT
);

INSERT INTO KaiTable
VALUES
  (
    'John'
   ,'A'
   ,5
  ),
('Ben ' ,'D' ,6),
('John' ,'A' ,5),
('Ben ' ,'A' ,5) ,
('John' ,'B' ,8) ,
('Ben ' ,'D' ,6) 

SELECT NAME,city 
FROM 
    (SELECT NAME,city,SUM(people) AS PeopleSum 
    FROM KaiTable 
    GROUP BY NAME, city 
    ORDER BY NAME ASC, PeopleSum DESC) AS a 
GROUP BY NAME DESC;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c92e8/3/0)